# Applying a displaced texture to a complex object

Tags: texturing, subdivision-surface, 3d-printing, displacement, multiresolution

I'm referring to the displacement modifier in Blender Render in this case because I want this 3D printed. It's purpose is to mask the layer lines produced from an FDM machine.

I'm trying to add a displaced wood texture like so:

[image]

Onto a complex object like this:

[image]

I tried the displacement modifier and texture painting but the results were sub par and inconsistent. Whats the best way to apply a realistic texture to an object that will actually displace the mesh geometry?

Comment: have you subdivided your mesh enough?

Comment: Yes, even with 6 million faces the results looks nothing like the texture.